# displaying xml file content within php

Tags: php

i have xml file( product.xml) and i need to display the whole content( including xml declaration , tags and node values) of this file within php program. how can i achieve that?

products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<product onshelf="yes">          
<type>cosmetic</type>          
<address>   
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb> 
</address>      
</product>  
<product onshelf="yes">          
<type>cosmetic</type>          
<address>   
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb> 
</address>      
</product>  
</products>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<product onshelf="yes">          
<type>cosmetic</type>          
<address>   
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb> 
</address>      
</product>  
<product onshelf="yes">          
<type>cosmetic</type>          
<address>   
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb> 
</address>      
</product>  
</products>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('product.xml')); ?>
```

The question is a bit misleading. Properly formalized:
How can I display the raw XML in a **browser** using PHP.

Comment: After 51 answers you should know that you need to indent code by 4 spaces... :P

Comment: @deceze Actually, end the backtick as I used single line code. :P

Comment: it shows only node values but not showing xml decelaration and tags.i mean in the same format as it is stored in "product.xml" file